# Setting a "dependency property" in code

Tags: wpf, binding, code-behind, dependency-properties

I'm on a roll today...

I have the following code delaring a dependency property inside a class called ActionScreen:

```
#region Dependency Properties & Methods

public string DescriptionHeader
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionHeaderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DescriptionHeaderProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DescriptionHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionHeaderProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DescriptionHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ActionScreen), new UIPropertyMetadata("xxx"));

#endregion
```

I bind to this property in my Xaml as so:

```
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Header="{Binding DescriptionHeader}" Width="350" />
```

Now I want to be able to set the parameter from my code behind when I recieve an event - but it's not working:

```
public string DescColText { set { this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { DescriptionHeader = value; })); } }
```

Comment: The text doesn't appear on my page when I run DescColText = "blah";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi resolved this I was not setting the datacontext of the page.

Apparently I needed to do

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: No. `DataContext=this;` is always wrong. It will break bindings on the control itself. The correct answer was to give the binding the correct source: `Header="{Binding DescriptionHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ActionScreen}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue.  It seems that the depedency property change does not fire a notification that the property has in fact changed. You have to do this manually.  In your code behind, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and in your dependency property registration, add the PropertyChangedCallback  delegate. (example)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionHeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DescriptionHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ActionScreen), new UIPropertyMetadata("xxx", new PropertyChangedCallback(DisplayTextChange)));

    private static void DisplayTextChange(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                ((WhatEverYourClassNameIs)dpo).NotifyPropertyChanged("DescriptionHeader");

            }
```

Here's the example of the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

That should allow your UI to see that a change has occured.

Comment: Hmmm this looks so close to what I want. My only issue now is that PropertyChanged is null so it's never firing the event. Where do I add the event handler for this?

Comment: You wouldn't add a handler for PropertyChanged.

Check your Output window.  Make sure there are no databinding errors (They would start with "System.Windows.Data Error: ")

Comment: This answer fails to address the issue, and provides wrong information. Dependency properties raise a notification when their values change. It is never necessary for a dependency object to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The problem was that the property is a property of `ActionScreen`, not of `ActionScreen`'s DataContext, which is the default source for the binding. The correct answer was to give the binding the correct source: `Header="{Binding DescriptionHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ActionScreen}}"`.